# How to improve Monte Carlo simulation?

Tags: excel, vba, montecarlo

I have written code to store individual results of a Monte-Carlo simulation in one sheet.

The macro stores the values of B6:DS6 in the Simulation Output(1) sheet after each iteration in an array and writes them finally below row 6.

The calculations take rather long, e.g. 15 minutes for 10.000 iterations.
Also when I run simulations of more than 5.000 I often get either of the following error messages.

[Error Message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMCNs.png)
or
[Error Message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxadp.png)

Any help on the errors and to make the code faster?

```vb
Sub MC_Sim()

'Varianblendeklaration
Dim Arr
Dim Outp
Dim i As Integer
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim MyTimer As Double

'Funktionen Aus
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("Simulation Output (2)").EnableCalculation = False
Sheets("Grafiken").EnableCalculation = False

'Timer für Simulationszeit
StartTime = Timer

'Szenario auf Monte Carlo Simulation setzen
Sheets("Annahmen").Select
    Range("F41").Select
    Range("F41").Value = "Monte Carlo Simulation"

'Löschen vorhandener Werte in Outputsheet
Sheets("Simulation Output (1)").Select
    Range("B7:DS7").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents

'Kopieren und Output der Simulationswerte in Schleife über ein Array als Zwischenpspeicher
ReDim Outp(1 To Range("C1").Value, 1 To Range("B6:DS6").Columns.Count)

For i = 1 To Range("C1")
    Arr = Range("B6:DS6").Value
    For S = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
        Outp(i, S) = Arr(1, S)
    Next
    
    'Neuberechnung der Planzufallswerte in B6:DS6
    Calculate
            
    'Ausgabe Stausbar
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    Application.StatusBar = "Simulation aktiv... I Fortschritt: " & i - 1 & " von " & Range("C1") & " Iterationen (" _
      & Format((i - 1) / Range("C1"), "0%") & ") I Rechenzeit (Min:Sek): " & Format(SecondsElapsed / 60 / 60 / 24, "nn:ss")
    
Next
        
'Zurückschreiben der Werte aus dem Array in das Tabellenblatt
Range("B7").Resize(UBound(Outp, 1), UBound(Outp, 2)) = Outp

'Simulationszeit in Sekunden
Sheets("Simulation Output (1)").Select
    Range("C2").Value = SecondsElapsed

'Szenario zurück auf Base Case
Sheets("Annahmen").Select
    Range("F41").Select
    Range("F41").Value = "Base Case"

'Simulationszeit in Sekunden
Sheets("Simulation Output (1)").Select
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    Range("C2").Value = SecondsElapsed

'Hinweis
MsgBox "Ende der Simulation! Rechenzeit (Min:Sek): " & Format(SecondsElapsed / 60 / 60 / 24, "nn:ss")

'Funktionen An
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Sheets("Simulation Output (2)").EnableCalculation = True
Sheets("Grafiken").EnableCalculation = True

'Zurücksetzen der Statusleiste und Löschen des Clipboards
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: If you have working code that you want to have peer reviewed for improvements, you should be asking at [codereview.se], which was created just for that purpose. This site is for questions about non-working code.

Comment: [Consider using long instead of integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689021/11732320)

Comment: Welcome Oscar! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your next badge. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me: Give it a try!

```
Option Explicit
Sub MC_Sim()
    
    'Varianblendeklaration
    Dim Arr
    Dim Outp
    Dim I As Long
    Dim S As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim Xval As Long
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
    Dim MyTimer As Double
    
    'Funktionen Aus
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    'Timer für Simulationszeit
    StartTime = Timer
    
    'Szenario auf Monte Carlo Simulation setzen
    Sheets("Annahmen").Range("F41").Value = "Monte Carlo Simulation"

    'Löschen vorhandener Werte in Outputsheet
    With Sheets("Simulation Output (1)")
        Lrow = .Range("B7").End(xlDown).Row
        .Range("B7:DS" & Lrow).ClearContents
            
        'Kopieren und Output der Simulationswerte in Schleife über ein Array als Zwischenpspeicher
        Xval = .Range("C1").Value
        ReDim Outp(1 To Xval, 1 To .Range("B6:DS6").Columns.Count)
        
        For I = 1 To Xval
            Arr = .Range("B6:DS6")
            For S = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
               Outp(I, S) = Arr(1, S)
            Next S
                
            'Neuberechnung der Planzufallswerte in B6:DS6
            Calculate
                        
            'Ausgabe Stausbar
            SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
            Application.StatusBar = "Simulation aktiv... I Fortschritt: " & I - 1 & " von " & Xval & " Iterationen (" _
            & Format((I - 1) / Xval, "0%") & ") I Rechenzeit (Min:Sek): " & Format(SecondsElapsed / 60 / 60 / 24, "nn:ss")
                
        Next I
                
        'Zurückschreiben der Werte aus dem Array in das Tabellenblatt
        .Range("B7").Resize(UBound(Outp, 1), UBound(Outp, 2)) = Outp
        
        'Simulationszeit in Sekunden
        .Range("C2").Value = SecondsElapsed
        
        'Szenario zurück auf Base Case
        Sheets("Annahmen").Range("F41").Value = "Base Case"
        
        'Simulationszeit in Sekunden
        SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
        .Range("C2").Value = SecondsElapsed
        
        'Hinweis
        MsgBox "Ende der Simulation! Rechenzeit (Min:Sek): " & Format(SecondsElapsed / 60 / 60 / 24, "nn:ss")
        
    End With
    
    'Funktionen An
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
    'Zurücksetzen der Statusleiste und Löschen des Clipboards
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```